# Github pages build fails when using nested front matter

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

so far I've defined and used images in my blog post this way:

```
---
image: "/media/pic001.jpg"
---
<img src="{{page.image}}" />
```

Now, I've wanted to also include an `alt` tag, so I've restructured my frontmatter:

```
---
image:
    url: "/media/pic01.jpg"
    alt: "Some image alt text"
---
<img src="{{page.image.url}}" alt="{{page.image.alt}}" />
```

When using `bundle exec jekyll build` locally, this runs perfectly fine and my site builds without problems. But when I push on Github, the page build fails (without any specific error message).

What's the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I possibly found the issue: `jekyll-feed` expects the image url as `image.path` instead of `image.url`. To avoid this issue, either rename the variable in the front matter (`picture.url` or the like), or use the given `image.path` to parse the feed correctly.